# Kibana and "not" queries

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I just installed an ELK stack (1 t3.medium with ES & Logstash, 1 t2.micro with Kibana).
So I can finally have a look at my logs and above all, do some learning around this stack !

I have a lot of logs like this one :
`run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-49fe22a2acfc527a65a195a0797694d933f00ce5771e927b8d99f6efaab1f161-runc.IfVJYS.mount: Succeeded.`

I found a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63622619/docker-flooding-syslog-with-run-docker-runtime-logs) but before removing all the logs, I wanted to do some filtering inside Kibana to not see them.

I tried to do the following:

- KQL: `message: docker and not message: "*mount*Succeeded*"`
- KQL: `not message: "*mount: Succeeded."`
- Lucene: `NOT message: "*mount: Succeeded."`

Any of theses queries removed the kind of message above.

What do I do wrong ? :)

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, lucene indexes "words", and the word start with `run` and finish with `mount` here.

So the Lucene query should be more like `NOT message: "run*mount" AND NOT message: "Succeeded."`